# How to store a list of objects temporarily

Tags: java, android, sqlite, onresume, onpause

I have a list of objects which need to persist should the user minimize the app. Is there any way to do this without using SharedPreferences or an SQLite database (seems like overkill for a single list)?

Comment: There is a Developer's Guide on [Data Storage](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html), it covers the most popular ways to do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a tutorial I found [here](http://android-er.blogspot.ie/2011/01/example-of-using-sharedpreferencesedito.html), I implemented it using SharedPreferences, the main difference was that instead of using a key ,"MEM1", I use an Index. When my activity loads, I can check the size of the index using this code,

```
for(int x =0; ;x++) {
    index = x;
    if(sharedPreferences.contains(String.valueOf(x))){
        temp = gson.fromJson(sharedPreferences.getString(String.valueOf(x), null), PointOfInterest.class);
        pointList.add(temp);
    }
    else {
        break;
    }
}
```

Example:

```
public class AndroidSharedPreferencesEditor extends Activity {

EditText editText1, editText2;
TextView textSavedMem1, textSavedMem2;
Button buttonSaveMem1, buttonSaveMem2;

   /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);

       textSavedMem1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.savedmem1);
       textSavedMem2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.savedmem2);
       editText1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext1);
       editText2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext2);
       buttonSaveMem1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.save_mem1);
       buttonSaveMem2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.save_mem2);

       buttonSaveMem1.setOnClickListener(buttonSaveMem1OnClickListener);
       buttonSaveMem2.setOnClickListener(buttonSaveMem2OnClickListener);

       LoadPreferences();
   }

   Button.OnClickListener buttonSaveMem1OnClickListener
    = new Button.OnClickListener(){

  @Override
  public void onClick(View arg0) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   SavePreferences("MEM1", editText1.getText().toString());
   LoadPreferences();
  }

   };

   Button.OnClickListener buttonSaveMem2OnClickListener
 = new Button.OnClickListener(){

  @Override
  public void onClick(View arg0) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   SavePreferences("MEM2", editText2.getText().toString());
   LoadPreferences();
  }

   };

   private void SavePreferences(String key, String value){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(key, value);
    editor.commit();
   }

   private void LoadPreferences(){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    String strSavedMem1 = sharedPreferences.getString("MEM1", "");
    String strSavedMem2 = sharedPreferences.getString("MEM2", "");
    textSavedMem1.setText(strSavedMem1);
    textSavedMem2.setText(strSavedMem2);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have the object implement [Parclable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) or [Serializable](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html)

Then you can just put it in the Bundle

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putParcelableArrayList(key, value);
}
```

And get it back in onCreate(),onRestoreInstanceState() depending on your needs.

Comment: will it work even when the activity is finished , for example when the OS decided it needs more memory ? i think it won't , and if @Tom wants to have it always stay for the next time , he must use SQL/sharedPreferences .

Comment: @androiddeveloper Yes, it will. The JavaDoc states `the process hosting the activity may killed by the system at any time without another line of its code being executed. Because of this, you should use the onPause() method to write any persistent data (such as user edits) to storage. In addition, the method onSaveInstanceState(Bundle) is called before placing the activity in such a background state, allowing you to save away any dynamic instance state in your activity into the given Bundle, to be later received in onCreate(Bundle) if the activity needs to be re-created.`